# Why Is WebMatrix Erroring When I Try To Manually Edit Long Strings With the Data Type ntext in SQL Server CE (Do I Need SQL Encoding)?

Tags: jquery, sql, json, sql-server-ce, webmatrix

Firstly, I am in an ASP.NET Web-Pages using WebMatrix with C# environment, which uses SQL Server Compact (SQL Server CE).

I had never heard of needing any kind of SQL encoding on anything before, but after this scenario happened to me, I thought I'd better make sure (I started by Googling "SQL Encoding" and while I did get some info, the results didn't really shed much light on my scenario, I thought):

I have a database and I am trying to save a potentially large string to it.

This string originally comes from an html `<textarea>` element, gathered with jQuery, like so:

```
agendaLines = $("#agendaText").val().split("\n");
```

It is then sent to the server via AJAX using `JSON.stringify(agendaLines)`

Once there, and still in string form, I simply `INSERT` it into my database with a simple `INSERT` statement along with some other values.

This long string gets inserted just fine, with no errors, but the problem is, if I were to try to "manually" (i.e., not in a query) perform some kind of action on that row, WebMatrix throws an error (which I assume has to be because of characters like `"`, `[`, `]`, `;`, `,`, or possibly others). This isn't really a problem since I don't plan on manually editing or deleting any of the rows, and if I did really need to I could just use a query, which seems to work fine. It does, however make me very suspicious as to whether I should expect any other errors, database crashes, or possibly security holes in the future for some reason.

Here is the output of `JSON.stringify(agendaLines)`:

```
["A G E N D A  ",""," ","","Okmulgee City Council, regular session, Tuesday, December 17, 2013 at 5:00 p.m. in the Council Chambers of City Hall, 111 East Fourth Street, Okmulgee, Oklahoma.",""," ","","CALL TO ORDER"," ","","Roll Call of Members"," ","","Pledge of Allegiance to the Flag of the United States"," ","","Invocation"," ","","MINUTES - Consider and vote to approve with any necessary corrections"," ","","November 19, 2013, special session","November 19, 2013, regular session"," ","","CLAIMS - Consider and vote to approve and authorize payment of such."," ","","COMMUNICATIONS – Not included on the agenda"," ","","ORDER OF BUSINESS"," ","","A) Consider and take action with respect to a resolution of the city council of the city of Okmulgee, Oklahoma (the “City”) approving the incurrence of indebtedness by the Okmulgee municipal authority (the “Authority”) issuing its utility system and sales tax revenue note, series 2013 (the “note”); providing that the organizational document creating the authority is subject to the provisions of the indenture authorizing the issuance of the note; waiving competitive bidding with respect to the sale of the note and approving the proceedings of the authority pertaining to the sale of said note; ratifying and confirming the sales tax agreement by and between the city and the authority pertaining to the year-to-year pledge of certain sales tax revenues; ratifying and confirming the lease agreement, pertaining to the city’s utility systems; and containing other provisions relating thereto.",""," ","","B) Presentation by Joe Prentice concerning damages to the Okmulgee Police Department.",""," ","","C) Consider and vote to approve retirement benefits for Jeremy Porter.",""," ","","D) Consider and vote to adopt an ordinance on standards for oversized loads being trucked through the city in which the standards are all contained in existing state law and/or metro Tulsa ordinances; and declaring an emergency.",""," ","","E) Consider and vote to approve, approve conditionally or disapprove the preliminary plat of Okmulgee Business Complex, a portion of the SE quarter of Section 31, T-14-N, R-13-E, Indian base and meridian Okmulgee County, State of Oklahoma.",""," ","","F) Consider and vote to approve acceptance of a bid for the purchase of two (2) Ford AWD police utility vehicles from the lowest, most responsible bidder and authorize the Mayor and City Clerk to execute the necessary documents.",""," ","","G) Consider and vote to approve a lease Extension for a period of an additional six months on the Eldon Day Lease.",""," ","","H) Consider and possibly both grant and accept the donation of a public utility easement for the City of Okmulgee.",""," ",""," I) Consider and vote to approve the appointment of Jack J. Willis or Brian Priegel to the Planning and Zoning Commission.",""," ","","                 J) Consider and vote to approve appointment of a representative of the governing body and an alternate to the Indian Nations Council of Governments (INCOG) Board of Directors.",""," ","","                K) Consider and vote to hold an executive session to discuss the potential hiring of a new Okmulgee City Manager. At the conclusion of the executive session, the Council will reconvene to take such action as may be useful or appropriate to hire or appoint a new City Manager, change the proposed benefit package, or eliminate individual candidates from the applicant pool as they deem useful.  Authority for an executive session is 25 O.S. § 307B1.",""," ","","6. INFORMATION ITEMS",""," ","","Community Development monthly report","Okmulgee Police Department monthly report","Fire Department monthly report","Legal Department monthly report","Finance Department monthly report","Technology Services monthly report","Financials","City Manager’s Report"," ","","7.   COMMENTS AND INQUIRIES FROM COUNCIL",""," ","","8.  ADJOURNMENT","","","","A G E N D A  ",""," ","","Okmulgee Municipal Authority, regular session, Tuesday, December 17, 2013 at 5:00 p.m. in the Council Chambers of City Hall, 111 East Fourth Street, Okmulgee, Oklahoma.",""," ","","CALL TO ORDER"," ","","Roll Call of Members"," ","","MINUTES - Consider and vote to approve with any necessary corrections."," ","","November 19, 2013, regular session"," ","","3. CLAIMS – Consider and vote to approve and authorize payment of      such. (See attached Claims List on City Council Meeting.)",""," ","","4.  ORDER OF BUSINESS",""," ","","A)  Consider and take action with respect to a resolution authorizing the Okmulgee Municipal Authority (the “Authority”) to issue its utility system and sales tax revenue note, taxable series 2013 (the “note”) in the aggregate principal amount of not to exceed $4,000,000.00; waiving competitive bidding and authorizing the note to be sold on a negotiated basis; ratifying and confirming the sales tax agreement by and between the city and the authority pertaining to a year-to-year pledge of certain sales tax revenue; approving and authorizing execution of a series 2013 supplemental note indenture authorizing the issuance and securing the payment of the note; providing that the organizational document creating the authority is subject to the provisions of the indenture; ratifying and confirming the lease agreement, pertaining to the city’s utility systems; authorizing and directing the execution of the note and other documents relating to the transaction; and containing other provisions relating thereto.",""," ","","B) Consider and vote to approve selecting which Option, 1) 1 acre cell construction with leachate storage pond, 2) 3 acre cell construction with leachate storage pond, 3) 4.83 acre cell construction with leachate storage pond and completing the sumps for the existing waste and building a transfer station as submitted by Shepherd Engineering for the Okmulgee Landfill.",""," ","",""," ","","5.   INFORMATION ITEMS   ",""," ","","Public Works monthly report","Wastewater Treatment Plant monthly report","Water Treatment Plant monthly report","Okmulgee Regional Airport monthly report"," ","","6.   ADJOURNMENT","","","","A G E N D A",""," ","","The Okmulgee Economic Development Authority will meet in regular session on Tuesday, December 17, 2013 at 5:00 p.m. in the Council Chambers of City Hall, 111 East Fourth Street, Okmulgee, Oklahoma.",""," ",""," ","","1. CALL TO ORDER",""," ","","A. Roll Call of Members",""," ","","2. MINUTES – Consider and vote to approve with any necessary corrections.",""," ","","A. November 19, 2013, regular session",""," ","","3. CLAIMS – Consider and vote to approve and authorize payment of such. (See attached Claims List on City Council Meeting.)",""," ","","4. ADJOURNMENT","","","","","","","","",""]
```

Am I right in assuming that the "manual" errors I get are just a result of the WebMatrix interface?

**Things You May Want To Know:**

The WebMatrix error I get when trying to manually edit the database through WebMatrix:

```
Your change could not be committed to the database.
After you click OK you can fix the invalid entry or press the Esc key to cancel your changes.

@WhereParam1 : String truncation: max=4000, len=6760, value='["A G E N D A  ",""," ","","Okmulgee City Council, regular session, Tuesday, December 17, 2013 at 5:00 p.m. in the Council Chambers of City Hall, 111 East Fourth Street, Okmulgee, Oklahoma.",""," ","","CALL TO ORDER"," ","","Roll Call of Members"," ","","Pledge of Allegiance to the Flag of the United States"," ","","Invocation"," ","","MINUTES - Consider and vote to approve with any necessary corrections"," ","","November 19, 2013, special session","November 19, 2013, regular session"," ","","CLAIMS - Consider and vote to approve and authorize payment of such."," ","","COMMUNICATIONS – Not included on the agenda"," ","","ORDER OF BUSINESS"," ","","A) Consider and take action with respect to a resolution of the city council of the city of Okmulgee, Oklahoma (the “City”) approving the incurrence of indebtedness by the Okmulgee municipal authority (the “Authority”) issuing its utility system and sales tax revenue note, series 2013 (the “note”); providing that the organizational document creating the authority is subject to the provisions of the indenture authorizing the issuance of the note; waiving competitive bidding with respect to the sale of the note and approving the proceedings of the authority pertaining to the sale of said note; ratifying and confirming the sales tax agreement by and between the city and the authority pertaining to the year-to-year pledge of certain sales tax revenues; ratifying and confirming the lease agreement, pertaining to the city’s utility systems; and containing other provisions relating thereto.",""," ","","B) Presentation by Joe Prentice concerning damages to the Okmulgee Police Department.",""," ","","C) Consider and vote to approve retirement benefits for Jeremy Porter.",""," ","","D) Consider and vote to adopt an ordinance on standards for oversized loads being trucked through the city in which the standards are all contained in existing state law and/or metro Tulsa ordinances; and declaring an emergency.",""," ","","E) Consider and vote to approve, approve conditionally or disapprove the preliminary plat of Okmulgee Business Complex, a portion of the SE quarter of Section 31, T-14-N, R-13-E, Indian base and meridian Okmulgee County, State of Oklahoma.",""," ","","F) Consider and vote to approve acceptance of a bid for the purchase of two (2) Ford AWD police utility vehicles from the lowest, most responsible bidder and authorize the Mayor and City Clerk to execute the necessary documents.",""," ","","G) Consider and vote to approve a lease Extension for a period of an additional six months on the Eldon Day Lease.",""," ","","H) Consider and possibly both grant and accept the donation of a public utility easement for the City of Okmulgee.",""," ",""," I) Consider and vote to approve the appointment of Jack J. Willis or Brian Priegel to the Planning and Zoning Commission.",""," ","","                 J) Consider and vote to approve appointment of a representative of the governing body and an alternate to the Indian Nations Council of Governments (INCOG) Board of Directors.",""," ","","                K) Consider and vote to hold an executive session to discuss the potential hiring of a new Okmulgee City Manager. At the conclusion of the executive session, the Council will reconvene to take such action as may be useful or appropriate to hire or appoint a new City Manager, change the proposed benefit package, or eliminate individual candidates from the applicant pool as they deem useful.  Authority for an executive session is 25 O.S. § 307B1.",""," ","","6. INFORMATION ITEMS",""," ","","Community Development monthly report","Okmulgee Police Department monthly report","Fire Department monthly report","Legal Department monthly report","Finance Department monthly report","Technology Services monthly report","Financials","City Manager’s Report"," ","","7.   COMMENTS AND INQUIRIES FROM COUNCIL",""," ","","8.  ADJOURNMENT","","","","A G E N D A  ",""," ","","Okmulgee Municipal Authority, regular session, Tuesday, December 17, 2013 at 5:00 p.m. in the Council Chambers of City Hall, 111 East Fourth Street, Okmulgee, Oklahoma.",""," ","","CALL TO ORDER"," ","","Roll Call of Members"," ","","MINUTES - Consider and vote to approve with any necessary corrections."," ","","November 19, 2013, regular session"," ","","3. CLAIMS – Consider and vote to approve and authorize payment of      such. (See attached Claims List on City Council Meeting.)",""," ","","4.  ORDER OF BUSINESS",""," ","","A)  Consider and take action with respect to a resolution authorizing the Okmulgee Municipal Authority (the “Authority”) to issue its utility system and sales tax revenue note, taxable series 2013 (the “note”) in the aggregate principal amount of not to exceed $4,000,000.00; waiving competitive bidding and authorizing the note to be sold on a negotiated basis; ratifying and confirming the sales tax agreement by and between the city and the authority pertaining to a year-to-year pledge of certain sales tax revenue; approving and authorizing execution of a series 2013 supplemental note indenture authorizing the issuance and securing the payment of the note; providing that the organizational document creating the authority is subject to the provisions of the indenture; ratifying and confirming the lease agreement, pertaining to the city’s utility systems; authorizing and directing the execution of the note and other documents relating to the transaction; and containing other provisions relating thereto.",""," ","","B) Consider and vote to approve selecting which Option, 1) 1 acre cell construction with leachate storage pond, 2) 3 acre cell construction with leachate storage pond, 3) 4.83 acre cell construction with leachate storage pond and completing the sumps for the existing waste and building a transfer station as submitted by Shepherd Engineering for the Okmulgee Landfill.",""," ","",""," ","","5.   INFORMATION ITEMS   ",""," ","","Public Works monthly report","Wastewater Treatment Plant monthly report","Water Treatment Plant monthly report","Okmulgee Regional Airport monthly report"," ","","6.   ADJOURNMENT","","","","A G E N D A",""," ","","The Okmulgee Economic Development Authority will meet in regular session on Tuesday, December 17, 2013 at 5:00 p.m. in the Council Chambers of City Hall, 111 East Fourth Street, Okmulgee, Oklahoma.",""," ",""," ","","1. CALL TO ORDER",""," ","","A. Roll Call of Members",""," ","","2. MINUTES – Consider and vote to approve with any necessary corrections.",""," ","","A. November 19, 2013, regular session",""," ","","3. CLAIMS – Consider and vote to approve and authorize payment of such. (See attached Claims List on City Council Meeting.)",""," ","","4. ADJOURNMENT","","","","","","","","",""]'.

System.InvalidOperationException: @WhereParam1 : String truncation: max=4000, len=6760, value='["A G E N D A  ",""," ","","Okmulgee City Council, regular session, Tuesday, December 17, 2013 at 5:00 p.m. in the Council Chambers of City Hall, 111 East Fourth Street, Okmulgee, Oklahoma.",""," ","","CALL TO ORDER"," ","","Roll Call of Members"," ","","Pledge of Allegiance to the Flag of the United States"," ","","Invocation"," ","","MINUTES - Consider and vote to approve with any necessary corrections"," ","","November 19, 2013, special session","November 19, 2013, regular session"," ","","CLAIMS - Consider and vote to approve and authorize payment of such."," ","","COMMUNICATIONS – Not included on the agenda"," ","","ORDER OF BUSINESS"," ","","A) Consider and take action with respect to a resolution of the city council of the city of Okmulgee, Oklahoma (the “City”) approving the incurrence of indebtedness by the Okmulgee municipal authority (the “Authority”) issuing its utility system and sales tax revenue note, series 2013 (the “note”); providing that the organizational document creating the authority is subject to the provisions of the indenture authorizing the issuance of the note; waiving competitive bidding with respect to the sale of the note and approving the proceedings of the authority pertaining to the sale of said note; ratifying and confirming the sales tax agreement by and between the city and the authority pertaining to the year-to-year pledge of certain sales tax revenues; ratifying and confirming the lease agreement, pertaining to the city’s utility systems; and containing other provisions relating thereto.",""," ","","B) Presentation by Joe Prentice concerning damages to the Okmulgee Police Department.",""," ","","C) Consider and vote to approve retirement benefits for Jeremy Porter.",""," ","","D) Consider and vote to adopt an ordinance on standards for oversized loads being trucked through the city in which the standards are all contained in existing state law and/or metro Tulsa ordinances; and declaring an emergency.",""," ","","E) Consider and vote to approve, approve conditionally or disapprove the preliminary plat of Okmulgee Business Complex, a portion of the SE quarter of Section 31, T-14-N, R-13-E, Indian base and meridian Okmulgee County, State of Oklahoma.",""," ","","F) Consider and vote to approve acceptance of a bid for the purchase of two (2) Ford AWD police utility vehicles from the lowest, most responsible bidder and authorize the Mayor and City Clerk to execute the necessary documents.",""," ","","G) Consider and vote to approve a lease Extension for a period of an additional six months on the Eldon Day Lease.",""," ","","H) Consider and possibly both grant and accept the donation of a public utility easement for the City of Okmulgee.",""," ",""," I) Consider and vote to approve the appointment of Jack J. Willis or Brian Priegel to the Planning and Zoning Commission.",""," ","","                 J) Consider and vote to approve appointment of a representative of the governing body and an alternate to the Indian Nations Council of Governments (INCOG) Board of Directors.",""," ","","                K) Consider and vote to hold an executive session to discuss the potential hiring of a new Okmulgee City Manager. At the conclusion of the executive session, the Council will reconvene to take such action as may be useful or appropriate to hire or appoint a new City Manager, change the proposed benefit package, or eliminate individual candidates from the applicant pool as they deem useful.  Authority for an executive session is 25 O.S. § 307B1.",""," ","","6. INFORMATION ITEMS",""," ","","Community Development monthly report","Okmulgee Police Department monthly report","Fire Department monthly report","Legal Department monthly report","Finance Department monthly report","Technology Services monthly report","Financials","City Manager’s Report"," ","","7.   COMMENTS AND INQUIRIES FROM COUNCIL",""," ","","8.  ADJOURNMENT","","","","A G E N D A  ",""," ","","Okmulgee Municipal Authority, regular session, Tuesday, December 17, 2013 at 5:00 p.m. in the Council Chambers of City Hall, 111 East Fourth Street, Okmulgee, Oklahoma.",""," ","","CALL TO ORDER"," ","","Roll Call of Members"," ","","MINUTES - Consider and vote to approve with any necessary corrections."," ","","November 19, 2013, regular session"," ","","3. CLAIMS – Consider and vote to approve and authorize payment of      such. (See attached Claims List on City Council Meeting.)",""," ","","4.  ORDER OF BUSINESS",""," ","","A)  Consider and take action with respect to a resolution authorizing the Okmulgee Municipal Authority (the “Authority”) to issue its utility system and sales tax revenue note, taxable series 2013 (the “note”) in the aggregate principal amount of not to exceed $4,000,000.00; waiving competitive bidding and authorizing the note to be sold on a negotiated basis; ratifying and confirming the sales tax agreement by and between the city and the authority pertaining to a year-to-year pledge of certain sales tax revenue; approving and authorizing execution of a series 2013 supplemental note indenture authorizing the issuance and securing the payment of the note; providing that the organizational document creating the authority is subject to the provisions of the indenture; ratifying and confirming the lease agreement, pertaining to the city’s utility systems; authorizing and directing the execution of the note and other documents relating to the transaction; and containing other provisions relating thereto.",""," ","","B) Consider and vote to approve selecting which Option, 1) 1 acre cell construction with leachate storage pond, 2) 3 acre cell construction with leachate storage pond, 3) 4.83 acre cell construction with leachate storage pond and completing the sumps for the existing waste and building a transfer station as submitted by Shepherd Engineering for the Okmulgee Landfill.",""," ","",""," ","","5.   INFORMATION ITEMS   ",""," ","","Public Works monthly report","Wastewater Treatment Plant monthly report","Water Treatment Plant monthly report","Okmulgee Regional Airport monthly report"," ","","6.   ADJOURNMENT","","","","A G E N D A",""," ","","The Okmulgee Economic Development Authority will meet in regular session on Tuesday, December 17, 2013 at 5:00 p.m. in the Council Chambers of City Hall, 111 East Fourth Street, Okmulgee, Oklahoma.",""," ",""," ","","1. CALL TO ORDER",""," ","","A. Roll Call of Members",""," ","","2. MINUTES – Consider and vote to approve with any necessary corrections.",""," ","","A. November 19, 2013, regular session",""," ","","3. CLAIMS – Consider and vote to approve and authorize payment of such. (See attached Claims List on City Council Meeting.)",""," ","","4. ADJOURNMENT","","","","","","","","",""]'.
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.FillParameterDataBindings(Boolean verifyValue)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, ResultSetOptions options)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.DatabaseManager.SqlCeDatabase.SqlCeDatabaseProvider.EditRowInternal(DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, String tableName, String schema, IList`1 columnDataInfoList)
   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.DatabaseManager.SqlCeDatabase.SqlCeDatabaseProvider.EditRow(String connectionString, String tableName, String schema, IList`1 columnDataInfoList)
   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.DatabaseManager.IisDbManagerModuleService.EditRow(DatabaseConnection databaseConnection, String tableName, String schema, ArrayList columnDataInfoArrayList, String configPathState)
   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.DatabaseManager.Client.ClientConnection.EditRow(String name, String schema, ArrayList columnDataInfo)
   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.DatabaseManager.Client.ClientTable.EditRow(ArrayList columnData)
   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.DatabaseManager.Client.DataView.EditRow(RowData rowData, Object[] originalValues)
```

- The data type of the field storing this string is `ntext` because of SQL Server CE's lack of support for `nvarchar(max)` (highest you can get is `nvarchar(4000)`)
- There is no interface for reading this value FROM the database, as it is just for logging purposes.

Comment: That's a bug in the WebMatrix data management tooling. Try making the update programmatically instead.

Comment: @MikeBrind Okay, that's what I thought. I don't feel so bad then. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't setting myself up for database failure or anything. If you don't mind making a quick answer, I'll be happy to upvote & acccept. Thanks, Again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bug in the WebMatrix data management tooling. Try making the update programmatically instead.